# how to use a function of another package correctly - android

Tags: android, package

I've a main package named `omer.ludlowcastle` and another package `omer.ludlowcastle.utils`

I wrote this function in `omer.ludlowcastle.utils` :

```
public boolean checkInternet (){
    final ConnectivityManager conMgr =  (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
    final NetworkInfo activeNetwork = conMgr.getActiveNetworkInfo();
    if (activeNetwork != null && activeNetwork.isConnected()) {
        return true;
    } else {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "You are not connected to Internet", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        return false;
    }
}
```

and I use this function in an activity in the main package as :

```
public void Login (View v){
    if(omer.ludlowcastle.utils.functions.checkInternet()){
        //do other stuff
    }

    else {
        //do other stuff
    }
}
```

but the line in the braces of `if` gives the following error :

`Cannot make a static reference to the non-static method checkInternet() from the type functions`

How to solve this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are getting **Cannot make a static reference to the non-static method checkInternet() from the type functions** because method is not static. You have 2 options:

1. Either declare the class Functions and method checkInternet() as static. It is more appropriate way as it is method of Utility class. So you can call it as you are using it right now.

2.Or create an object of class as

```
Functions funObj = new Functions();
```

And then call method using object as

```
public void Login (View v){
    if(funObj.checkInternet()){
        //do other stuff
    }

    else {
        //do other stuff
    }
}
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

Make the method static:

```
public static boolean checkInternet()
```

or, get an object of whatever class the checkInternet function is in, and call its `checkInternet()` function, but it's probably less resource intensive to make a static method.

Comment: I was getting error the checkInternet() by making the method static ..

But the things worked by creating an object of the class ..  thanx ... :D

Comment: sorry .. right now I've deleted that part of code ...
But I'll tell you later for sure because I also want to fix that problem ..

Answer (score 0):

You have to set your methods in utils package as static.

```
public static boolean checkInternet()
```

Utility classes are for make static methods and they are not saving states, so if you write a utility class, the methods have to be static. It is the general use.

Answer (score 0):

Modify your method and make it static

```
public static boolean checkInternet (){
    final ConnectivityManager conMgr =  (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
    final NetworkInfo activeNetwork = conMgr.getActiveNetworkInfo();
    if (activeNetwork != null && activeNetwork.isConnected()) {
        return true;
    } else {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "You are not connected to Internet", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        return false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just make your method as static:

```
public static boolean checkInternet (){
    final ConnectivityManager conMgr =  (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
    final NetworkInfo activeNetwork = conMgr.getActiveNetworkInfo();

    if (activeNetwork != null && activeNetwork.isConnected()) {
        return true;
    } else {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "You are not connected to Internet", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        return false;
    }
}
```